# Как отправить форму в Python, используя модуль requests

Tags: html, python, requests

С помощью модуля requests я прохожу авторизацию на сайте и попадаю на страницу, где есть нужные данные. На этой странице есть фильтр с чекбоксом. У тега select name = data_id[], а id нужного пункта равен 82.
Я пишу такой запрос:

```
url = 'http://www.site.ru'
data = {"data_id[]":"80"}
response = session.post(url, data=data)
```

Но response.text возвращает все ту же страницу сайта, где параметры фильтра не применены. Что я делаю не так? В браузере если выбрать нужные элементы и нажать "Применить фильтр", то возвращается страница http://www.site.ru/index.php и фильтр работает.

Comment: Зависит от сайта. Лучше всего в таком случае использовать локальный прокси, который протоколирует все запросы, исходящие от браузера (к примеру, Postman или Apache JMeter), и затем сравнить запрос браузера с твоим. Браузеры тоже протоколируют запросы, к примеру в хроме открой таб Network в Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось всё проще, чем я думал. Передавая фильтр из формы нужно указывать все элементы всех фильтров, даже если они пустые:

```
data = {'number':'' 
,'mobile_phone':''
,'date_start':''
,'date_end': ''
,'filter': ''}
```

Таким образом response.text возвращает уже страницу с примененными фильтрами. Все фильтры можно посмотреть в браузере Network -> All -> Form data